# Laravel Queue Not working as expected. Row inserted in table but not attempted

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

What I have done so far:

1) Updated queue driver to database in .env

2) My mail controller function looks like:

```
public function sendEmail()
{
   $emailJob = (new SendEmailJob())->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(3));
   dispatch($emailJob);
    exit();
}
```

3) SendEmailJob handle

```
public function handle()
{
    Mail::to('mail@gmail.com')->send(new SendMailable());
    echo 'email sent';
}
```

4) SendMailable Mail has following

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.ownership');
}
```

I want to send mail almost instantly after hitting the url.
As I am running `php artisan queue:listen` with delay of 3 seconds it takes a lot of time before  any action. I can see some data on jobs table with 0 attempts.

After long time, following error popup in command window

```
   Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException  : The process ""C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.10\php.exe" "artisan" queue:work  --once --queue="default" --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=0" e
xceeded the timeout of 60 seconds.

  at C:\wamp64\www\project\vendor\symfony\process\Process.php:1154
    1150|
    1151|         if (null !== $this->timeout && $this->timeout < microtime(true) - $this->starttime) {
    1152|             $this->stop(0);
    1153|
  > 1154|             throw new ProcessTimedOutException($this, ProcessTimedOutException::TYPE_GENERAL);
    1155|         }
    1156|
    1157|         if (null !== $this->idleTimeout && $this->idleTimeout < microtime(true) - $this->lastOutputTime) {
    1158|             $this->stop(0);

  Exception trace:

  1   Symfony\Component\Process\Process::checkTimeout()
      C:\wamp64\www\project\vendor\symfony\process\Process.php:383

  2   Symfony\Component\Process\Process::wait()
      C:\wamp64\www\project\vendor\symfony\process\Process.php:202
```

By, the way mail can be sent directly without this queue stuff. Also, is this compulsory to run php artisan queue:listen? How am I supposed to run this in server with no shell access?

Answer (score 0):

```
The process exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds
```

It's no surprise that to resolve this, you must increase the timeout of your job. To do so, you can either use the `--timeout` option in the `queue:work` command to increase the timeout to say `180` seconds or define the variable in your job class like so: `public $timeout = 180;`

From the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#job-expirations-and-timeouts),

**1. Use --timeout**

> The maximum number of seconds that jobs can run may be specified using
>   the --timeout switch on the Artisan command line

**2. Use $timeout**

> You may also define the maximum number of seconds a job should be
>   allowed to run on the job class itself. If the timeout is specified on
>   the job, it will take precedence over any timeout specified on the
>   command line

To your other questions:

> Is this compulsory to run php artisan queue:listen?

No

> How am I supposed to run this in server with no shell access?

Use [Supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#supervisor-configuration) or [Laravel Horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/horizon) (in case you're using Redis for the queue)